# Как из дива сделать кнопку?

Tags: html, css

Имеется такая верстка

```css
    .rectangles_block
{
margin-left:21%;
margin-top:16%;
position: absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
.rectangle
{

margin-bottom:10px;
width: 338px;
height: 72px;
background: #4E5661;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.41);
box-sizing: border-box;
box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangles_block">
<div class ="rectangle"><p class="rectangle_text ">Дозвонился. Договорились!</p></div>
<div class ="rectangle"><p class="rectangle_text ">Дозвонился. Не договорились!</p></div>
<div class ="rectangle"><p class="rectangle_text ">Не дозвонился!</p></div>
</div>
```

Выглядит сие "чудо" следующим образом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но у меня не получается сделать из них активные кнопки, если использую тег button все очень жестко съезжает, что делать?

Comment: а что вы подразумеваете под "сделать кнопку" ? Могу предложить на .rectangle добавить cursor:pointer; + навесить стилей :hover + для красоты какой нибудь transition

Comment: имеется в виду - сделать кликабельную штуку, которая по нажатию на нужный элемент будет отправлять что то на сервер

Comment: тогда я бы на вашем месте обратил внимание на JS или библиотеку JQuery, как обработчика  и отправителя ваших данных. Если же не подходит JS|JQuery, то переделвыйте в формЫ эти кнопки и сабмитте данные через них.

Comment: Просто загвоздка в том, что можно использовать только html + css